# Magento get all orders numbers shipped as overnight between two dates

Tags: mysql, magento

Title pretty much describes it, I just need to get all the order numbers
shipped with Overnight shipping between 6-8 to 6-12.

Help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is at least one way of achieving this...

```
$from           = "2012-06-08";
$to             = "2012-06-12";
$shippingMethod = "overnight_shipping";

$orderIds = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_shipment_collection')
                ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array(
                    'from'  => $from,
                    'to'    => $to,                    
                 ))
                ->getColumnValues('order_id')
             ;

$incrementIds = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_collection')
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('shipping_method', array('eq' => $shippingMethod))
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $orderIds))
                        ->getColumnValues('increment_id')
                ;

echo "<ul>";
foreach($incrementIds as $incrementId) {
    echo "<li>" . $incrementId . "</li>";
}
echo "</ul>";
```

Comment: @Drew Great answer!