# automatically capture payment from paypal in magento

Tags: magento, paypal

I am using magento 1.7.0.
I have integrated paypal on my magento store.and I have choose payment_action authorization in paypal express checkout method.Now I want capture payment automatically after two day.Is Any solution how to capture payment automatically?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a setting to capture a payment automatically after 2 says within Magento, but you could create your own interface for doing this if you wanted to using PayPal's [DoCapture API](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/docapture-api-operation-nvp).  If you wanted to automate the process, you could create a script for doing this and set up a cron job to check the date of the transaction and perform the capture.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ http://www.sumoheavy.com/capturing-payment-on-shipment-creation-magento/ and http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-orders/automatically-invoice-ship-complete-order-in-magento/

Create a magento cron job ([see](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job)). In your cron job search for all orders that is older than 2 days and less than 'X' days, payment method is paypal and order status is `pending`

```
//$orders = get order filter see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11042343/magento-get-all-orders-numbers-shipped-as-overnight-between-two-dates

foreach($orders as $order){
    if(check payment type and status){

        if (!$order->canInvoice()) {
                return $this;
        }

        $invoice = Mage::getModel('sales/service_order', $order)->prepareInvoice();
        if (!$invoice->getTotalQty()) {
                return $this;
        }


        $invoice->setRequestedCaptureCase('online');
        $invoice->register();
        $invoice->getOrder()->setIsInProcess(true);
        $transactionSave = Mage::getModel('core/resource_transaction')
        ->addObject($invoice)
        ->addObject($invoice->getOrder());

        $transactionSave->save();
    }
}
```